# I am using Model from react native but In bottom side showing gray background space

Tags: android, react-native

I research multiple times but didn't get any solution, please let me if I am doing wrong.
Here is the code for better understanding. 
The black space is bottom navigation bar but I don't want the bottom navigation bar

```
<Modal
animationType="fade"
transparent={true}
visible={true}
>
<View style={styles.popupOverlay}></View>
<View>test</View>
</Modal>

popupOverlay:{
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)', 
flex:1,
height:hp("105%"),
},
```

[image]

Comment: So you wanted to display a transparent background?

Comment: Also please mention which modal you are using because `Modal from React-Native is deprecated`

Comment: Yes I am using modal from react-native

Comment: I want fullscreen overlay

Comment: are you sure it is not related to `safeAreaView`?

Comment: @HagaiHarari yes I try but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to find a solution:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal

use this
statusBarTranslucent={true}